# Can't automate LoadRunner tests from Powershell using HP ALM Rest API

Tags: powershell, loadrunner

I am trying to use PowerShell commands to fire a specific LoadRunner test.  The test has been designed as part of the HP ALM interface.

HP documentation gives complete details of the REST API here:
http://alm-help.saas.hp.com/en/12.50/api_refs/REST/webframe.htm#Overview.htm

There seems to be no reason why this should not be fired from standard PowerShell commands, but I can't find examples anywhere of how to do this, and the HP reference only contains Java examples (there are a few short C# examples on line as well).

Does anyone know of any examples which I can refer to?  Or are you able to share any PS scripts which you may have working?

RSVP - thanks

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Do you want to launch a Loadrunner test from ALM and store the results in ALM? Do you have Performance Center or just Loadunner?

Comment: We have Performance Center hosted in HP enterprise (cloud based).  There is a predefined test which I want to fire externally from a Powershell script (rather than from an HP script authored in VueGen).  We want to run the powershell from a step in a Bamboo CI deployment, to immediately performance-test a new deployment using LoadRunner.

Comment: Just looking for resources which will help me with the Powershell syntax for authenticating, starting an ALM session, firing the LoadRunner test and downloading the results using Powershell to make calls to the REST API - there seem to be no examples out there of how to do this....

Comment: Ah ok you mentioned ALM, but you want to use PC. The PC REST API is actually different to the ALM API. http://alm-help.saas.hp.com/en/12.50/api_refs/Performance_Center_REST_API/Performance_Center_REST_API.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here is some untested code which should do the trick.

Here's the Performance Center REST API documentation:
http://alm-help.saas.hp.com/en/12.50/api_refs/Performance_Center_REST_API/Performance_Center_REST_API.htm

You're going to have to give Basic Authentication to the first authentication request and use the cookie value for the next POST request.

```
$PC_SERVER = "servername"

$headers = @{}
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Headers $headers -Uri http://$PC_SERVER:8080/qcbin/authentication-point/authenticate

$runrequest = "<Run xmlns=`"http://www.hp.com/PC/REST/API`"> <PostRunAction>Collate And Analyze</PostRunAction> <TestID>5</TestID> <TestInstanceID>4</TestInstanceID> <TimeslotDuration> <Hours>1</Hours> <Minutes>30</Minutes> </TimeslotDuration> <VudsMode>false</VudsMode></Run>"

$headers = @{}
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Headers $headers -body $runrequest -Uri http://$PC_SERVER:8080/LoadTest/rest/domains/{domainName}/projects/{projectName}/Runs


$headers = @{}
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Headers $headers -Uri http://$PC_SERVER:8080/qcbin/authentication-point/logout
```

Comment: This will trigger the test, but how to download the result which is a html , so that i could parse it and use.